# Android Permissions and Partitions

Tags: android, security

I wanted to try dual booting on both my phones. My devs have posted that we should check out our /system partition and see if we have enough space, a simple 'DF' through a terminal emulator. What I saw surprised me. I've used Linux for a long time and this is the first I saw this kind of behavior.

Many apps/games have their own 'hidden' partition. An unisntallation doesn't technically 'fix and merge' said uninstalled app and add to whichever partition they stole it from (can someone confirm which, I'd like to know).

I'd like something that can do this for me, and to scan whether or not a new-going-to-install app will do this to me. I don't have the Play Store installed, so I manually install them from sites I trust.

(hopefully used the 'security' tag correctly, as I feel this is a 'forced' aspect)

Comment: The technical background would rather be something for our Android sister site, but still: I've never heard of that behavior. What makes you believe this is the case – and you're not misinterpreting something (like the fact that apps moved to SD card are using a "secure/encrypted container", which might look like a separate partition but should rather be seen as a "mounted image file")? So if you misinterpreted that (not saying you did, but IF), the app you're looking for might not exist at all.

Comment: ah so it seems i was overreacting a bit. the partition i was referring to were folders inside the /mnt/asec directories. its sort of sad how they dont clean up after themselves. id still like some kind of an automated mnt/asec cleaner. sdmaid doesnt do them yet i think.

Comment: Yeah, thought so – and thought exactly about `/mnt/asec`, which simply corresponds to the "container" located in the `.android_secure` ("a_sec", see?) folder on the SD card.

Comment: yep that part, would be nice if an app were uninstalled, those containers should be unmounted/removed as well. IMO its easier to newly flash rather than using a terminal to fully fix them. do you have any suggestions for an app to do this for me?

Comment: Nope, sorry. I cannot remember ever having used App2SD (which is usually behind that) at all. Also, this is the first time I hear it leaves those containers behind on deinstallation. And if it's just you, I'm afraid there won't be an app to clean this up. Wait: Cleanup? Worth a try at least: Take a look at *SD Maid,* which is known doing a good job on getting rid of remains from uninstalled apps. Might take care of your issue as a side-effect :)

Comment: im pretty sure sdmaid does do that, but at a cost. the last time ive used it, it also killed off some other games along with the uninstalled traces. since im about to reflash both of my phones i might as well retry sdmaid and hope that problem is fixed

Comment: It's quite a while ago that I've used SDMaid last, so your feedback is welcome! If it works out fine, consider answering your own question :)